# New Beta Theme Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Your site looks a bit different today. Yes, we are getting rid of the 'Sketchy' look and replacing it with a more-polished and finished design for sites in beta.

You can read more about the redesign of our Beta theme on our [blog entry](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/the-new-stack-exchange-beta-theme-2/).

Please note: This will not affect your "graduation" status in any way. When your site is due for graduation, it will get its final(real) site design and branding.

If you're still seeing the old favicon, please do a hard browser refresh. (Although sometimes it may take Chrome a while to load the new image).

If you see any CSS or styling issues, please report it **[in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126185/new-stack-exchange-beta-theme)** I created on Meta Stack Overflow. It will be easier for me to track all the bug reports there.

Answer (score 6):

I liked the 'Sketchy' look more than this one.

Answer (score 5):

It's a pleasant re-design, although I think the "question" title in the questions listing could do with being bolder - the contrast between text and background is getting quite low now.

Comment: Yeah, the main navigation could be stronger, but I pretty much like everything else.

Answer (score 2):

The Mathematica.SE logo on the chat page is designed for a bright background, but it is shown on a dark background:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Could you change the background back to bright?

Answer (score 1):

The user and search information in the dark blue (black in meta) bar at the top of the page doesn't show up in IE7, so I can't actually tell if I'm logged in when I'm at work.

I suppose this is fixed in IE8, so I'll have to wait until we upgrade to Windows 7 next month.

Comment: Unfortunately we no longer support IE7 since it's an ancient browser. Are you able to use FF or Chrome at work?

Comment: No, sorry. IT department rules. But we're going to Windows 7 next month, so it is a transient problem.

Answer (score 1):

I find the font size in code blocks to be too small, and smaller than the rest of the post.  Code is often central and it should *not* be the most difficult part to read.

With full page zoom in Firefox this is what I see:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I find the code blocks a pleasant size to read and much better than the earlier one. As always, not everyone will be satisfied :)